# Sharepoint & Development License

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

In one of my project, we are stuck with a weird license policy, quite possible that we may have limited knowledge on how share point licensing works but would appreciate if anyone could shed light on this topic.

Our organization have a full blown version of share point enterprise installation, we are building app using share point as a core foundation and our development team size may grow from 20-30. I was told by the team that each developer will need a personal copy of sharepoint server installed on their local machine for development purpose, once they are done with their local development, the apps are then promoted to our enterprise dev environment. However, in order to get personal copy of sharepoint server, i need to buy a MSDN Premium Subscription that cost around 6K. We do have Visual Studio licenses bought for the team. So it means technically i am shelling out 6K * 30 = 180K just towards development license, also keep in mind we have paid a hefty price to purchase sharepoint enterprise server.

I am interested in knowing how other people are managing this, I wish Visual Studio had a sharepoint web server shell similar to how it bundles up with local web server for development purpose before promoting it to IIS.

We are also looking into using 180 days of trial version of sharepoint, this would allow each of our developer to install trial version and do their local development and once they are done with their testing, they can then promote and test it out using our enterprise sharepoint dev servers. Most of our developers will be released in 5 months.

Thanks in advance for your help.